# Add products to Cart using cart.php in Big Commerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying add product to cart using http post in remote.php like

```
POST /cart.php HTTP/1.1
Host: mobfirst.mybigcommerce.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action=add&product_id=35&variation_id=currency_id=&attribute[66]=11&qty[]=1
```

It works, but I wonder know how figure out the number of attribute corresponding to option product (66 in attibute[]). I saw it is dynamic.

ps: I can't use the api to create order because I don't have the billing address at this moment.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Yes, I did. I add it as right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer of support:

I actually did not know of a way to find that attribute number other than scraping the product page. Digging and testing some things just now though I have found where it comes from.

It appears that attribute number comes from the "product option ID" number which you can pull from the API (not to be confused with the "option ID" number). The easiest way to explain would be with an example, say I wanted to find the attribute numbers for a product with ID 50. I would make a GET request to:

https://domain.com/api/v2/products/50/options

This would give me back a list of "product option" objects that will look similar to this:

```
[ 
{ 
"id": 199, 
"option_id": 75, 
"display_name": "Option 1", 
"sort_order": 0, 
"is_required": true 
}, 
{ 
"id": 200, 
"option_id": 76, 
"display_name": "Other Option", 
"sort_order": 1, 
"is_required": true 
} 
]
```

The ID number seen will be unique to that specific product and matches up with the attribute number used when making a POST to add the product to cart. In this case my product has 2 options, both required, and the attribute numbers will be 199 and 200. To find the IDs for the values I have to look up the option values themselves, such as for ID 199, the option is ID 75. To pull up the values for option ID 75 I would make a GET to something like:

https://domain.com/api/v2/options/75/values

If I used option 75 on a different product it will have a *different* "product option ID".